# Llenar un grid view con una consulta que trae nulos

Tags: c#

Tengo mi código que llena un gridview que a su vez contiene un repeater.
Al momento de llenar ese grid con un procedimiento almacenado de consulta, me manda el error: Mi variable Embarazo no esta definida. No trae registros esa consulta, pero si quiero que se visualice mi grid.

Comment: Saludos Stack es un lugar de colaboración mutua deberias agregar tu codigo para poder acotar con ideas y posibles soluciones.

Comment: Bienvenido @Saul Alexander a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Te serviría  la propiedad GridView.EmptyDataTemplate ?